# Why doesn't my Python program reach the intended website?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am attempting to make a web scraper in Python 3. I keep getting a WinError 10060 stating that the connection failed because the connected party did not properly respond or the connected host failed to respond. Using both the urllib and also trying with requests libraries both create the 10060 error. When using requests the error states they the max retries exceeded with the URL.

```
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org') as response: 
    html = response.read()
```

People have mentioned that it is likely a proxy or firewall issue as I am attempting to do this on my work network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a proxy authentication error. Simply adding the proxy with your credentials in the get command solved this.

```
proxies = {'http': 'http://user:pass@url:8080', 'https': 'http://user:pass@url:8080'}
page = requests.get(webpage, proxies)
```